# in my website data for my iphone & ipad are those websites that only i have looked at?

Tags: iphone, ipad

When I look at my website data I keep seeing websites showing up in there that I know for a fact I would of never pulled up or looked on.

For example: there was one for baby names, I can't have kids and have never pulled up sites for that.

Can it be that someone is hacking into my phone and ipad cause there's a lot of suspicious sites that aren't mine?

Answer (score 2):

If you share an iCloud account with someone, or someone is signed into you iCloud account on another device, the history may sync to your personal devices.

Answer (score 1):

If by website data you mean the History you can access from Safari on either your iPhone or iPad, then **no it doesn't mean you've been hacked.**

Instead, by having iCloud activated and Safari synced via iCloud, this means that any Apple device also using the same iCloud account with Safari sync activated can access/view pages quickly that you've previously opened (or have open) on another device.

By way of example, in Safari on your iPhone or iPad, if you tap on the Tabs icon at the bottom right this will bring up all your open Tabs. With your tabs visible, slide up and eventually you'll see a list of all pages currently open in Safari on your iPad, Mac, etc assuming you've logged into the same iCloud account and have chosen to sync Safari.

This is a great feature allowing you to quickly access a page you know you've got open on another device. For example, you may have researched a new fridge on your Mac and then you're in a store looking at fridges and can't quite remember something you read, so by getting your iPhone out you can either use the Tabs icon to quickly access what you know you still have open in Safari on your Mac, or go into the History to see what you had looked at.

If you're concerned about privacy, you can set up multiple user accounts on your Mac and have each one signed into a separate iCloud account.

My wife and I use separate accounts on our iMac and can each access our own separate browsing history, what tabs we have open, etc on our respective devices, .

Of course, you can also switch off Safari syncing in your iCloud settings as well.

Hope this helps.